# python and boto : 403 accessDenied

Tags: python, amazon-s3, boto

```
import boto
from boto.s3.connection import S3Connection
from boto.s3.connection import OrdinaryCallingFormat

conn = S3Connection(access_key, secret_key, calling_format=OrdinaryCallingFormat())
bucket = conn.get_bucket(file_name)
print(bucket.name)
```

And the console display:

```
raise err
boto.exception.S3ResponseError: S3ResponseError: 403 Forbidden
```

I have seen many post about the same problem but I can't figure out how to solve it... 
note that I am not the owner of the bucket, but I succeed to connect and download the file with a gui tool. I need to process it by script for automation.

EDIT:
Succeed to connect, but still struggling...
I begin to hesitate to process it automatically rather than manually ...

```
    conn = S3Connection(access_key, secret_key, calling_format=OrdinaryCallingFormat())

bucket = conn.get_bucket(bucket_name, validate=False)
print('bucket:', bucket)
print('bucket.name:', bucket.name)

key = bucket.get_key(file_name)
print("key: {name}\t{size}\t{modified}".format(name = key.name,size = key.size,modified = key.last_modified))

print('bucket.list():',bucket.list(prefix='GA-Exports/Events_3112/DEV'))

for key in bucket.list(prefix='DEV/',delimiter='/'):
    print('bucket list -> key:',key)
```

console :

```
bucket: <Bucket: GA-Exports/Events_3112/>
bucket.name: GA-Exports/Events_3112/
key: DEV/EVENTS_3113_120002892.csv.gz   3826    Sat, 16 May 2015 10:05:44 GMT
bucket.list(): <boto.s3.bucketlistresultset.BucketListResultSet object at 0x0000000004E9F7F0>
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "D:\Python\lib\xml\sax\expatreader.py", line 207, in feed
    self._parser.Parse(data, isFinal)
xml.parsers.expat.ExpatError: no element found: line 1, column 0

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Francois\OneDrive\IDE\Workspace\eclipse\Python_test\etltest.py", line 31, in <module>
    for key in bucket.list(prefix='DEV/',delimiter='/'):
  File "D:\Python\lib\site-packages\boto\s3\bucketlistresultset.py", line 34, in bucket_lister
    encoding_type=encoding_type)
  File "D:\Python\lib\site-packages\boto\s3\bucket.py", line 472, in get_all_keys
    '', headers, **params)
  File "D:\Python\lib\site-packages\boto\s3\bucket.py", line 406, in _get_all
    xml.sax.parseString(body, h)
  File "D:\Python\lib\xml\sax\__init__.py", line 46, in parseString
    parser.parse(inpsrc)
  File "D:\Python\lib\xml\sax\expatreader.py", line 107, in parse
    xmlreader.IncrementalParser.parse(self, source)
  File "D:\Python\lib\xml\sax\xmlreader.py", line 125, in parse
    self.close()
  File "D:\Python\lib\xml\sax\expatreader.py", line 217, in close
    self.feed("", isFinal = 1)
  File "D:\Python\lib\xml\sax\expatreader.py", line 211, in feed
    self._err_handler.fatalError(exc)
  File "D:\Python\lib\xml\sax\handler.py", line 38, in fatalError
    raise exception
xml.sax._exceptions.SAXParseException: <unknown>:1:0: no element found
```

Comment: Is the bucket in the us-west-1 zone? I can see that you are not setting the zone anywhere

Comment: Actually I don't know where the bucket is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By default, boto will attempt to validate the bucket when you call `get_bucket` by performing a `HEAD` request on the bucket.  You may not have permission to do this even though you may have permission to retrieve objects from the bucket.  Try this to disable the validation step:

```
bucket = conn.get_bucket(bucket_name, validate=False)
```

Also, make sure you are passing in the name of the bucket.  Your example code is passing in `file_name` which doesn't sound right.

Comment: It is true that it is bucket_name rather than file_name.
For the validate=False, I tried but since I had doubt the bucket was really loaded I leave it aside, I reset it to false.  The Amazon access rights and the boto API documentation still seem rather obscure.

Comment: From the documentation: "To use HEAD, you must have READ access to the object." It is not possible to not have permission to use HEAD and have access to READ the object. Though you might be getting the 403 error because you may not have `s3:ListBucket` permission.  http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/API/RESTObjectHEAD.html